# Moving a subfloat to the background

Tags: graphics, floats

I have the following problem: i have a figure with 3 subsfigs, (2 top, 1 centered bottom). Since the background of the pictures is white and i want a good layout, I moved the bottom figure up with a `\vspace`. However, it overlaps the captions of the first two figures as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

(a and b are not readable anymore).

How can i move the last image to the background or behind the captions?

Thanks!

Code:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \subfloat[ ]{\label{STG_3M_2}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/CH5/3M/2_3}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{STG_3M_7}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/CH5/3M/7_3}} \\
    \center
    \vspace{-10mm}
     \subfloat[]{\label{STG_3M_10}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/CH5/3M/10_3}}
    \caption{Microstrain versus displacement at three specific locations for the 3M Scotch Weld 9323 B/A specimens which failed cohesively.}
    \label{STG_3M}
    \vspace{-5mm}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: if the images aren't prepared within (la)tex, it looks like they have excess white space above the legend at the top.  perhaps this could be removed with either an external cropping tool, or with a cropping option in the `\includegraphics` statement.

Comment: The problem is that I cant crop it into a non-rectangular image. As you can see, it is cropped right above the titel (3M_R_10).

Comment: @TiemenDeWinter this is  in memor class? ... off-topic: maybe a little trick help you:"make transparent background, this is possible with .png figures", but sometimes the result is not so good (the lines could be very thin, but you lose nothing to prove)

Comment: is the top edge tight against the title?  if i enlarge the image on the screen and hold up a straightedge, it looks like there's a bit of clearance.  try the option `trim= 0 0 0 2` where the fourth value specifies the number of `bp` that should be cropped.

Comment: @juanuni, no it is not in memoir class, i tried the transparency thing but it has no effect

Comment: @bararabeeton there was indeed a bit of clearance, i was able to crop a few milimeters off but the problem still exists

Comment: @TiemenDeWinter you need edit your figure with external program (like gimp, photoshop, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can include the image in the background, setting it in a `tikzpicture` that takes up no vertical space and where we can move objects as we please. The important thing is to draw the background picture before any other thing is printed.

I assume that the three images have the same height. In the third `\subfloat`, I just place a couple of invisible rules to set the box dimensions and make the subcaption appear correctly aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (background) at (0,-2\ht0+2cm) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\subfloat[]{\label{STG_3M_2}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[]{\label{STG_3M_7}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\subfloat[]{\label{STG_3M_10}\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0-1cm\relax}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}

\caption{Microstrain versus displacement at three specific locations for the 
         3M Scotch Weld 9323 B/A specimens which failed cohesively.}
\label{STG_3M}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the amount of shifting until you're satisfied. Note that a change to the parameters requires two LaTeX runs to be honored.

[image]